# What is the purpose of :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild] in a Leiningen project.clj file?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have been looking at several project templates for a Clojure/ClojureScript web application. Some have the following line in the Leiningen  project.clj

```
 :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
```

while others have not.

What is the purpose of this line? Why would you use it, and why not? Are there advantages, or disadvantages in using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:hooks` option is used for modifying built-in Leiningen tasks. All the details are described in [Leiningen's documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md#hooks).

[`leiningen.cljsbuild` hooks are adding ClojureScript support in lein's built-in tasks](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild#hooks): `compile`, `test`, `jar`.

It might be useful if your project contains both Clojure and ClojureScript files. By using the hook you can `compile`, `test` or package them in `jar` in one run using lein's built-in tasks instead of calling them separately for Clojure (built-in tasks) and ClojureScript with `lein-cljsbuild` tasks.

Comment: I read the docs, and from them I can't answer the questions I asked, can you? Do you use :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild], if so why, if not why not?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I understood that you were asking about `:hooks` in general. I have edited my answer to add the details on `leiningen.cljsbuild` hook.